# tmr.create() fails in dirt simple code

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

On an ESP8266, a LUA **tmr.create() fails**. Just a single line of code from the nodemcu docs. I've yet to get this working; stumped; have found nothing on the 'net here or forums. Posted in several other places with no replies. Odd

Basic node commands work. And, here's the thing that's getting me: some timer functions work - for instance tmr.alarm() does - but tmr.create() doesn't.

**QUESTION 1:** if the tmr module is loaded, isn't the *entire* module loaded, not just parts of it?

When I try this one line copied directly from the NodeMCU docs, it fails:

```
local mytimer = tmr.create()
```

with the usual message, I understand to mean an object is undefined:

```
stdin:1: attempt to call field 'create' (a nil value)
```

**QUESTION 2:** What am I missing or doing wrong?

Nodemcu's flasher successfully sent its default

INTERNAL://NODEMCU @ 0x00000

NodeMCU 0.9.5 build 20150318

The board is an Adafruit Huzzah ESP8266, not a NodeMCU board. They both use the same ESP12, I think, so that shouldn't matter (or I hope it doesn't :-/)

Comment: if tmr.alarm isn't nil, tmr.create shouldn't be nil as well. they are both provided by the same function in the firmeware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> NodeMCU 0.9.5 build 20150318

There's your culprit. That version is ancient. `create()` was added much later. Build a recent version from the master branch, https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/build/ (note `master` in the URL), and flash that one.

Comment: Thanks, Marcel. That did fix the problem!  Seems to be a lot of convoluted things and unexpected obstacles with these ESP's and especially with LUA --- at least when it's relatively new to you. (I've gotten stuff done a lot faster writing PIC asm code ! :)   It also doesn't help when board vendors preload a very old firmware version, but then give example code that, when only slightly tweeked, explodes because newer firmware is needed. %-| (Oh, well, this is what gives hacking its name, eh ?)